# Load Gif with animation in lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I used this code to load an image (gif)

```
image:TGIFImage;
implementation
{$R *.lfm}
{ TForm1 }
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
image:=TGIFImage.Create;
image.LoadFromFile('F:\ltdk\pic\bom.gif');
image3.Picture.Assign(image);
end;
```

but it doesn't work  , so I need know how to load gif with animation in lazarus ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Creating a TGIFImage and loading the GIF in it will only show a frame of the file, not animate it. In order to animate a GIF file you need some code.

You can check out these resources:

(The last message on this page:)
http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,14884.msg80387.html#msg80387

http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=7818.0